# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_project'

Tags: django

After running `makemigrations` Django falls with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_project'`

`$ python3 manage.py makemigrations`

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 308, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_project'
```

```py
import os

import netifaces

def ip_addresses():
    ip_list = []
    for interface in netifaces.interfaces():
        addrs = netifaces.ifaddresses(interface)
        for x in (netifaces.AF_INET, netifaces.AF_INET6):
            if x in addrs:
                ip_list.append(addrs[x][0]['addr'])
    return ip_list

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = '...'
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS =  ['...']


INSTALLED_APPS = ( 
    'django.contrib.admin', 
    'django.contrib.auth', 
    'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
    'django.contrib.sessions', 
    'django.contrib.messages', 
    'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
    'crispy_forms', 
    'accounts', 
    'hashtags', 
    'tweets', 
)  

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ( 
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware', 
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project.urls'
LOGIN_URL ="/login" 
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL ="/" 
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL ="/" 

TEMPLATES = [ 
    { 
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates', 
        'DIRS': [], 
        'APP_DIRS': True, 
        'OPTIONS': { 
            'context_processors': [ 
                'django.template.context_processors.debug', 
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth', 
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages', 
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.wsgi.application' 



DATABASES = { 
    'default': { 
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'), 
    }
}


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/django/django_project/static-serve'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/django/django_project/static-serve'
```

root@Tweets:/home/django/django_project/tweets# tree

```
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
├── __pycache__
│   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── admin.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── forms.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── mixins.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── models.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── validators.cpython-37.pyc
│   └── views.cpython-37.pyc
├── admin.py
├── admin.pyc
├── api
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── pagination.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── serializers.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── pagination.py
│   ├── pagination.pyc
│   ├── serializers.py
│   ├── serializers.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── apps.py
├── forms.py
├── forms.pyc
├── manage.py
├── migrations
│   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   ├── 0002_auto_20190622_1801.py
│   ├── 0002_auto_20190622_1801.pyc
│   ├── 0003_tweet_user.py
│   ├── 0003_tweet_user.pyc
│   ├── 0004_auto_20190623_0830.py
│   ├── 0004_auto_20190623_0830.pyc
│   ├── 0005_auto_20190623_1853.py
│   ├── 0005_auto_20190623_1853.pyc
│   ├── 0006_tweet_parent.py
│   ├── 0006_tweet_parent.pyc
│   ├── 0007_tweet_liked.py
│   ├── 0007_tweet_liked.pyc
│   ├── 0008_tweet_reply.py
│   ├── 0008_tweet_reply.pyc
│   ├── 0009_auto_20190625_1740.py
│   ├── 0009_auto_20190625_1740.pyc
│   ├── 0010_auto_20190627_1045.py
│   ├── 0010_auto_20190627_1045.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   └── __pycache__
│       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-37.pyc
│       ├── 0002_auto_20190622_1801.cpython-37.pyc
│       ├── 0003_tweet_user.cpython-37.pyc
│       ├── 0004_auto_20190623_0830.cpython-37.pyc
│       ├── 0005_auto_20190623_1853.cpython-37.pyc
│       ├── 0006_tweet_parent.cpython-37.pyc
│       ├── 0007_tweet_liked.cpython-37.pyc
│       ├── 0008_tweet_reply.cpython-37.pyc
│       ├── 0009_auto_20190625_1740.cpython-37.pyc
│       ├── 0010_auto_20190627_1045.cpython-37.pyc
│       └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
├── mixins.py
├── mixins.pyc
├── models.py
├── models.pyc
├── templates
│   └── tweets
│       ├── create_view.html
│       ├── delete_confirm.html
│       ├── form.html
│       ├── search_form.html
│       ├── tweet_detail.html
│       ├── tweet_list.html
│       └── update_view.html
├── tests.py
├── urls.py
├── urls.pyc
├── validators.py
├── validators.pyc
├── views.py
└── views.pyc

7 directories, 82 files
```

pip freeze

```
asn1crypto==0.24.0 
Avatar==0.1 
cryptography==2.1.4 
Django==1.11.11 
django-appconf==1.0.3 
django-avatar==4.1.0 
django-bootstrap3==11.1.0 
django-bootstrap4==0.0.8 
django-crispy-forms==1.7.2 
djangorestframework==3.9.4 
enum34==1.1.6 
gevent==1.2.2 
greenlet==0.4.12 
gunicorn==19.7.1 
gyp==0.1 
idna==2.6 
imagekit==1.0.6 
ipaddress==1.0.17 
keyring==10.6.0 
keyrings.alt==3.0 
netifaces==0.10.4 
Pillow==6.1.0 
psycopg2==2.7.4 
pycrypto==2.6.1 
pygobject==3.26.1 
PyICU==1.9.8 
pytz==2018.3 
pyxdg==0.25 
SecretStorage==2.3.1 
six==1.11.0 
sqlparse==0.2.4 
virtualenv==15.1.0
```

/home/django/django_project/django_project# tree

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
├── settings.py
├── settings.pyc
├── urls.py
├── urls.pyc
├── views.py
├── views.pyc
├── wsgi.py
└── wsgi.pyc
```

Comment: You need to add `django_project` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future seekers, after debugging, the issue was related to the manage.py file which was missing from the project directory.

Comment: Okey, would you please show your project folder structure

Comment: Not this one, i want to see what /home/django/django_project/ contains

Comment: Added to the top

Comment: wich server are you using ?

Comment: Really i cannot see where the problem is, but what i advise you to do is to run a development server within the same project on a vm on another port and check if you will get the same error, if it is not the case so the issue is related to the installation of Django on the server.

Comment: within the django_project you don't have a manage.py, you must have you settings file and the urls.py and wsgi.py, the error that you are getting as if the project it self does not exist which is something weird

Comment: yes within /home/django/django_project/ you must have a manage.py file

Comment: Yes on the application you don't have a manage.py file, try to copy it to the serc directory

Comment: Greate, glad that it helped, i have updated the answer if someone will run on the same issue.